# Why Néron model is a separated scheme?

Tags: elliptic-curves, schemes, group-schemes

Let $K$ be a local field and $R$ be ring of integers.
Néron model is defined as smooth group scheme over $\operatorname{Spec}R$, whose generic fiber is isomorphic to $E$, and satisfies Néron mapping property.

But I often hear Néron model is separated and finite type as a scheme.
How can I deduce Néron model is separated from this definition?

Comment: I think it’s in the definition.

Comment: Definition I know in Silverman's book 'Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves' don't assume neon model is separated and finite type.

Comment: Any reasonable definition of smoothness implies “locally finitely presented”. Separatedness is in the Wikipedia definition, at least.

Comment: I'm not sure if you necessarily can deduce it, but at least in Theorem 6.1 he shows that for $R$ a Dedekind domain, for elliptic curves $E/K$ ($K$ field of fractions of $R$) a separated Neron model exists. So if the ring of integers of a local field is a Dedekind domain you could just assume you are working with a separated model if needed.

Comment: @ Mindlack  Do you mean smooth scheme is always separated ?